# Pass a file/binary through laravel backend to laravel api

Tags: php, laravel

From my Vue frontend, I'm uploading a .glb file with a post request to my Laravel backend. The file arrives just fine there, however, I need to pass it futher to the api, which stores it in database blob as a binary.

Here are many variations I've tried, while way more are already deleted. At first, I was trying to send the file itself, but then I noticed that original 5MB file, which was still 5MB on backend was just 1B on api, so it wasn't getting through. Then I tried to post binary data itself, so api wouldn't need to get file contents, just store incoming data into the database. I was getting `Malformed utf-8 characters` from `json_encode` on backend, now I'm getting the same error on the side of api. And then when luckily some variation doesn't have the utf-8 malformation error, I find out that the file is back to 1B (empty) again.

Backend code:

```
public function uploadBinary(Request $r, $id)
{
    $file = $r->file('file');
    $bin = $file->get();
    // $bin = mb_convert_encoding($bin, 'UTF-8', 'auto');

    // $file->storePubliclyAs('', 'glbtest.glb');

    $res = Http::withToken(config('api.key'))
        ->acceptJson()
        ->withHeaders([
            // 'Content-Type' => 'model/gltf-binary'
            'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream'
        ])
        // ->withBody($bin, 'application/octet-stream')
        ->asMultipart()
        // ->attach('file', asset('glbtest.glb'))
        // ->post(replaceWildcards(config('api.urls.tdmodels.binary'), compact('id')));
        // ->post(replaceWildcards(config('api.urls.tdmodels.binary'), compact('id')), $bin);
        ->post(replaceWildcards(config('api.urls.tdmodels.binary'), compact('id')), [
            'file' => $bin
            // 'file' => file_get_contents(storage_path('app/glbtest.glb'))
        ]);

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'uplo',
        'body' => $res->body(),
        'sizebe' => $file->getSize(),
        'pathbe' => $file->path(),
        'asset' => asset('glbtest.glb'),
    ]);
}
```

Api code:

```
public function uploadBinary($id, Request $request)
{
    // $request->setJson(null);
    $tdmodel = Tdmodel::findOrFail($id);

    // $binaryData = $request->getContent();
    // $file = $request->file('file');
    // $binaryData = $file->getContent();

    // $tdmodel->binary_file = $request->getContent();
    // $tdmodel->binary_file = $binaryData;
    $tdmodel->binary_file = $request->file;
    $tdmodel->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Binary file uploaded successfully',
        // 'fileAPI' => $file->getSize()
    ]);
}
```

Can I send the file itself, but I'm missing something? Can I send the binary without Laravel's Http trying to json encode and decode the data?
I feel like this has to have a simple solution, yet I've already spent two days on it. Thank you.

### edit:

After some more testing, I got to version that uploads whole 5MB to the api, however still only 16B is uploaded to database. I also checked my my.ini where is cap high enough with `max_allowed_packet=512M`.

Backend:

```
public function uploadBinary(Request $r, $id)
{
    $file = $r->file('file');
    $bin = $file->get();

    $res = Http::withToken(config('api.key'))
        ->acceptJson()
        ->withBody($bin, 'application/octet-stream')
        ->post(replaceWildcards(config('api.urls.tdmodels.binary'), compact('id')));

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'uplo',
        'body' => $res->body(),
        'sizebe' => $file->getSize(),
    ]);
}
```

Api:

```
public function uploadBinary($id, Request $request)
{
    $tdmodel = Tdmodel::findOrFail($id);

    $binaryData = $request->getContent();
    $stream = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
    fwrite($stream, $binaryData);
    rewind($stream);

    $tdmodel->binary_file = $stream;
    $tdmodel->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Binary file uploaded successfully',
        'binlen' => strlen($binaryData),
        'fstat' => fstat($stream),
    ]);
```

`sizebe` from backend has value `5224096`
then from api response
`binlen:5224096`
`fstat\":{\"0\":12,\"1\":0,\"2\":33206,\"3\":1,\"4\":0,\"5\":0,\"6\":-1,\"7\":5224096,\"8\":0,\"9\":0,\"10\":0,\"11\":-1,\"12\":-1,\"dev\":12,\"ino\":0,\"mode\":33206,\"nlink\":1,\"uid\":0,\"gid\":0,\"rdev\":-1,\"size\":5224096,\"atime\":0,\"mtime\":0,\"ctime\":0,\"blksize\":-1,\"blocks\":-1}}`

which means im finally getting correct binary size on api side too, both in binary request content and the stream where i move it to.
but in database there is still only this:
[image: only 16B blob]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, i eventually just used guzzle and everything worked. 3 days of work in the bin.

```
public function uploadBinary(Request $r, $id)
{
    if (!$r->hasFile('file')) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Binary data not found'
        ], 404);
    }

    $file = $r->file('file');
    $binary = $file->get();

    $client = new Client();

    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => config('api.key_bearer'),
        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
    ];
    
    $res = $client->request('POST', replaceWildcards(config('api.urls.tdmodels.binary'), compact('id')), [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'body' => $binary,
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Uploaded successfully.',
    ]);
}
```